# using API Google Places details error Allow origin Cors React project

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, cors, google-places-api

I'm trying to use the Google Place API to get details of Places by their Id I'm using the service provided here https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

I'm developing on ReactJs

follows error image:

[image: embedded image]

I've seen around here that for these **Allow Origin** cases you should use Maps JavaScript API --> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details

However what is the best way to get a `google.maps` reference in a **REACTJS** project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to `react-google-maps` which is component based. it's community is huge.
Here is the working example of places API in `react-google-maps` make sure you have an API key. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/qqzm67ykmq

You need to get an API key first form [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials). Here are steps below for API key:

- Create a project
- Generate a API key
- Enable places API and Maps Javascript API
- Restrict your API key with these APIs

Comment: Thanks Sakni ! I resolved with vanilla javascript using as reference this code https://github.com/elharony/Udacity-P8-Neighborhood-Map-Project-Explained/blob/master/src/App.js .. That add the script Tag with the google Api URL into the DOM when the component is already Mounted .. works fine :)